# Windows Process won't communicate across a socket

Tags: python, windows, sockets, process, irc

I've been writing an IRC chatbot that checks Google Voice for SMS messages then relays them to the chatroom through a socket on port 6667. The chat message processing runs in the main sub, in an infinite loop, while the GV checking is done in a separate process. The actual checking and fetching works fine, but it's the socket that doesn't work; no message is posted to the channel. What's strange is that this works flawlessly under OS X, so I don't believe the problem is the Voice processing logic:

```
def checkVoice()
    while 1:
        print "Update voice!"
        #voice processing... edited for brevity
        sendPrivateMessage(CHANNEL,message) #This doesn't work
        #more code
        time.sleep(10)

#main block
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sendPrivateMessage(CHANNEL,"Voice checking started") #This works
    p = Process(target=checkVoice)
    p.start()
```

I assumed that the problem was with the way Windows is with Python, seeing as it works with other platforms.

The full code for the chatbot can be seen here:
[bot.py](http://thebox.it.cx/exe/bot/bot.py)

As asked, here is the `sendPrivateMessage` method:

```
def sendPrivateMessage(channel, message):#private message send function
    global mute
    if mute == 0:
            IRC.send("PRIVMSG " + channel + " :" + message + "\r\n")
```

Comment: Can you include the `sendPrivateMessage()` method and anything else that looks related?